# bigdecimal subtraction results in exponential

Tags: java, bigdecimal, exponential

I have the following code.

```
BigDecimal b1 = new BigDecimal("1.12345678912345678");
    BigDecimal b2 = new BigDecimal("1.12345678912345678");
    System.out.println(b1.subtract(b2));
```

The output is :
0E-17

How can I avoid the exponential format ? The method toPlainString of bigdecimal will return String and I do not want that. I want my bigdecimal object to be there without exponential value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling `println(Object)` method and it internally uses the `Object.toString()` method.

And from the [JavaDoc of `BigDecimal.toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#toString())

> Returns the string representation of this BigDecimal, **using scientific notation if an exponent is needed.**

Your statement about `toPlainString()` method and wanting a bigdecimal object doesn't make sense, since the difference is only between the `toString()` method and `toPlainString()` method (*Both of which return a string representation in different formats*). You will in both cases have the **same** `BigDecimal` object. And the difference is only while printing.

Comment: Actually i do not want to print.
Assume the result is b3 = b1- b2.
Now i want to add to b3 to b4. 
My goal is not to print. But to do some further calculations. Is that possible ?

Comment: @user2354566, yes it's possible... Just do all your calculations with the object... And at the end when you want to print it out use `toPlainString()` method.